# Why the ajax code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i'm new in asp MVC so I will try to make a login form with ajax so i write jsonresult to check the username and password in the controller and i call it in ajax but it's not working and i don't know why so that's my controller code

```
 public ActionResult login()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]

    public JsonResult ValidateUser(string username,string password)
    {
        using(var contxt=new EnglisCenterEntities())
        {
            var data = from a in contxt.Employee
                       where a.Username == username && a.Passwords == password
                       select a;
            if(data.Count()>0)
            {
                return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my view and ajax code

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 alert alert-warning">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning form-control" type="submit" id="savedata"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>&nbsp;Login</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
           <script>
                   $(document).ready(function () {
                       $('#savedata').click(function () {
                           var data = {
                               "username": $("#username").val(),
                               "password": $("#password").val()
                           };
                           $.ajax({
                               url: "/Account/ValidateUser",
                               type: "Post",
                               data: JSON.stringify(data),
                               dataType: "json",
                               contentType: "application/json",
                               success: function (response) {
                                   if (response.Success) {
                                       $.get("@Url.Action("Index", "Home")", function (data) {
                                           $('.container').html(data);
                                       });

                                   }
                                   else
                                       window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Login", "Account")";
                               },
                               error: function () {
                                   console.log('Login Fail!!!');
                               }
                           });
                       });
                   });
         </script>
```

Why it's not working ? any help please

Comment: is there a form? as you are using a submit button.

Comment: Define "not working".  What *is* it doing?

Comment: Your ajax request throws an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of `JSON.stringify`, modify your ajax call `data` as shown :-

```
$.ajax({
          url: "/Account/ValidateUser",
          type: "Post",
          data: data,
          dataType: "json",
          .....
});
```

Comment: Thanks  it's working now , but there other problem my username and password not connected with my jsonresult so when i put the right username and password doesn't send it in the pram

Comment: @MahmoudSamy...not able to get what you are trying to say ..now if you have another question post it as a separate thread on SO..please don't ask another question in comments section.If this answer solved your problem mark it as as accepted.

Comment: Thanks i will post another question thanks a lot for your answer and for your advice

Comment: @MahmoudSamy...happy to help you..:)